# How do I find the difference between today's date and X days from today?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

**Hello all,**

Having checked out all the possible threads that were presented before I asked my question, I didn't find an answer suitable for VB.net and MySQL.  Most dealt with Android and PHP.

So I'm trying to run a query against a date field in a table within my MySQL database that finds all the records with a date value that's X number of days from today.  How would I do this?

I using VS2010 and MySQL - in case I didn't already mention that.  Thanks.

//Kismet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE DATE(datecol) BETWEEN DATE(NOW()) AND DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL x DAY));
```

See [FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce78a/1)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the query is returning 0 records and I know for a fact that I have records in there that fall within the criteria of say 15 days from today.

Comment: I've added a fiddle showing that it works. Make sure you take time zones into account -- the fiddle site is running in GMT, so it says NOW() is Dec 21.

Comment: You're right it does work......I guess that then means I need to post another question.  It seems the query is looking for records that have a date value that is exactly the number of days from today.  What I'm trying to accomplish is all records that fall within the range of now + X number of days.  I do appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Now that you know about `date_add()` isn't it obvious how to do that?

Comment: haha, actually I took a stab at it and wound up with exactly what you came up with.  Thanks - really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

this is the query for MySQL and

> finds all the records with a date value that's X number of days from today

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE date_column = CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL X DAY
```

this one will find all records with a date value between today and X numbers of days from today

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE date_column BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE AND CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL X DAY
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, but the query is returning 0 records.  Now it shouldn't matter that the date is in the MySQL date format right?