# Filter a range of dates with SQL

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, symfony, filter

I have to filter the results of an SQL starting at the current day and displaying all records until the current day + 10 days. So if it's the 22th of December I should display all records starting that day and that aren't after the the 1st of January. How can I do this? I tried a simple query like the one below but it seems to only display the records until the last day of the current month and then instead of showing the records of the next year goes back to the first month of the current year.

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE DAY(mydatefield) >= DAY(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
  AND mydatefield <= DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 10 DAY)
```

**EDIT 1**

I'm using Symfony 2 + Doctrine 2 querybuilder so the query must be compatible with them

**EDIT 2**

I solved the Doctrine 2 problem by using the query suggested by eggyal with this PHP code

```
$queryBuilder->where($queryBuilder->expr()->gte('mydatefield', 'CURRENT_DATE()'))->andWhere($queryBuilder->expr()->lte('mydatefield', 'DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), 10, \'DAY\')'));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find the difference between today's date and X days from today?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13981334/how-do-i-find-the-difference-between-todays-date-and-x-days-from-today)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem lies in your erroneous use of MySQL's [`DAY()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_day) function, which returns the *day of the month*.  You should use instead [`DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date); you can also simplify with  the [`BETWEEN ... AND ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) comparison operator:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   mytable 
WHERE  DATE(mydatefield) BETWEEN CURDATE() AND CURDATE() + INTERVAL 10 DAY
```

Note that, in order to benefit from index optimisation, you could instead do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   mytable 
WHERE  mydatefield >= CURDATE() AND mydatefield < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 11 DAY
```

Comment: +1. Having the bare column in the comparison (vs. wrapped in a function) is really the way to go, in terms of making performance tuning possible.  And using the `>=` and `<` for the range comparison, that approach works for checking DATETIME ranges other than integer number of days, from midnight of one day to midnight of some another day.

Comment: I forgot to say that I'm using Doctrine 2 and PHP so the query will work only with plain SQL. I need a way to use it in doctrine querybuilder

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE date(mydatefield) >= date(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
  AND date(mydatefield) <= date(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 10 DAY))
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/592e9/13)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE DATE( mydatefield ) BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE AND CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 10 DAY
```